# ng2 select2 [data]. Not working if 'id' is different of 'text'

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I have a issue with ng2 select2 plugin for angular 4. Indeed, if my id is different of my text, the plugin bug and nothing is showing in the select2 after clicking on the dropdown value (value is "null")...

I just reproduce this component, (https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2-demo/tree/master/src/app/demos/basic) and I have the same problem... On init the value is showing well. But when I change the value of the input, the select doesn't show anythings... 
See bellow the few steps to understand what I mean.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does someone have a solution to solve this bug ? Thank you

Comment: Nobody have an answer ?

Comment: Hi All,
I want to use "idNumber" instead of "id" and "textData" instead of "text", Anybody have idea, How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get id via following code

```
console.log('changed value is '+event.data[0].id);
```

**component.html**

```
<select2 [data]="exampleData" [value]="startValue" [width]="150" (valueChanged)="handleChange($event)"></select2>
```

**component.ts**

```
handleChange(event):void {
   console.log('changed value is '+event.data[0].id);
}
```

Your event variable in the function parameter contains value like given below:

```
{  
   "value":"basic3",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "selected":true,
         "disabled":false,
         "text":"Basic 3",
         "id":"basic3",
         "element":{  

         }
      }
   ]
}
```